# Campo do tipo GEOGRAPHY

Tags: genexus

Como definir um campo do tipo GEOGRAPHY no GeneXus. Este campo é do SQL Server 2012. É com ele que calculamos as distâncias entre duas coordenadas geográficas (Latitude e Longitude)

Alguém pode me informar?

Comment: Ainda não temos suporte em GeneXus, mas se voce vem a o encontro GX25, pode ver [esta palestra](https://www5.genexus.com/meeting2015/gx25.EventSessions.aspx?#Session:3746), ou vai poder ver online depois

Answer (score 0):

O GeneXus possui um domínio semântico chamado  [Geolocation](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Geolocation%20Domain)

Esse domínio, quando vinculado à um atributo, não cria o tipo de dados GEOGRAPHY no SQL Server 2012, pois como a ferramenta é multi banco, para manter uma coerência, a informação é armazenada no formato caracter, com uma vírgula separando a latitude e a longitude, ex.: "-36.123 , -57.235".

Para saber a distância entre coordenadas, pode usar o método GetDistance da [API GeoLocationAPI](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?GetDistance%20Mehod).

Se precisar de mais apoio, podes me contatar pelo email gx2@gx2.com.br

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

A partir da versão [GeneXus 15](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27605,Toc%3AGeneXus%2015,) começa a se suportar o tipo de dados Geography nativo dos diferentes DBMS.

[Aqui](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?32408,Geography%20data%20type) tem mais informação.